# jQuery slide show not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have tried to have the [jQuery Slideshow](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow%5D) in one of my site, but it is now not working in IE9. It is working fine in all IE Versions till IE8.

Please help us to find out a way to make it work in IE9.

Comment: will you consider to show some code

Comment: First of all, define "not working."  Second, provide some code to reproduce the problem so we can actually help.

Comment: I have used the same code in the link provided. Can  you please be kind to view the link in IE 9 you can find that it it not working in IE9.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your reply, THe Same issue i have found in Galleria photogallery too. Can you please help me to figure out the actual problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to do is [upgrade to the latest version of jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) - it looks like you're currently using jQuery v1.4, but IE9 support was only introduced [in v1.5.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/02/24/jquery-151-released/).

**Update**: if the [IE9 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Usingtheconsole) don't reveal any script errors, and the code is still not displaying properly for you, you can always [force IE to render your website in IE8 mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Add the following meta tag between the `<head>` tags on every page which contains the slide show:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated the v1.5.1.But still i have the same issue. What about your thoughts regarding this? Any mistake from my side ?

Comment: The problem could be in many places - you'll need to provide more information to get a better answer.  Suggest you use the IE9 Developer Tools to locate the error, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx#Usingtheconsole

Comment: I am using the IE9 .http://202.137.248.5/nivo-slider/demo/demo.html You can see my link here . i ahve updated the JQUERy and in Developer tool i am not able to find the error. Please help

Comment: Oh! It Seems to be interesting ! Can you see the image sliding in IE9. For me it is not working. i can see only the loading image. it is also not moving. any other setting do i need to change in IE9

Comment: i have added this meta tag between head tag, but still i am not able to see the slideshown and no error is displayed.http://202.137.248.5/nivo-slider/demo/demo.html

Comment: I am using IE 9 with Version:9.0.8112.16421. Do anybody have the same issue in the same version ?

Comment: That's the version that I have.

Comment: 202.137.248.5/nivo-slider/demo/demo.html  May you please tell me you OS please where the link is working with sliding pictures

Comment: yes, its now worked for me too! THanks for your help and support

Comment: +1 for letting me know about the IE developer tools. It led me right to the problem, which incidentally was the jQuery bgIframe (which fixes problems in IE6). It turened out the check for the browser version was just checking for the string "6.0" in the user agent, so version 6.0 of any plug in or add on would fire the code.